# How to fix this System.UnauthorizedAccessException? C#

Tags: c#, exception, permissions

have an application that accesses a directory and via the SoundPlayer class I access a file. Wav.
I have the following C #:

```
public void PlaySound()
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            List<string> distinctMusicFile = GetMusicFile.Distinct().ToList();

            if (DataTableWorkCall.GetDataTableNew.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < distinctMusicFile.Count; i++)
                {
                    StopSound();
                    player.SoundLocation = distinctMusicFile[i];
                    player.Play();
                    Thread.Sleep(Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["MusicDuration"]) * 1000);
                    StopSound();
                }
            }
            else
                GetMusicFile.Clear();
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException e)
    {
        if (generateLog)
            log.LogTxt("Finished...\n");
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException e)
    {
        if (generateLog)
            log.LogTxt(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

This code is generating this exception:

```
Application: AndonGestamp_FormMonitoramento.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Stack:
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32, System.String)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(System.String, System.IO.FileMode,         System.IO.FileAccess, Int32, Boolean, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES, System.String, Boolean, Boolean)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(System.String, System.IO.FileMode, System.IO.FileAccess, System.IO.FileShare, Int32, System.IO.FileOptions)
   at System.IO.File.Create(System.String)
   at AndonGestamp_FormMonitoramento.Utils.Log.LogTxt(System.String)
   at AndonGestamp_FormMonitoramento.Utils.Music.PlaySound()
   at AndonGestamp_FormMonitoramento.Andon.ThreadPlayMusic()
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Log generation:

```
public void LogTxt(string msg)
    {
        string logDirectory = ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Log"].ToString();

        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(logDirectory))
        {
            System.IO.File.Create(logDirectory).Close();
        }

        if (msg != null)
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter file = System.IO.File.AppendText(logDirectory);
            file.WriteLine(msg + " " + DateTime.Now + "\n");
            file.Close();
        }

    }
```

The function log.LogTxt (String) creates a txt file, can this be?
Problems regarding permissions?
Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: `Problems regarding permissions?` I'd say that's a safe bet. Make sure that the process has read access to the files.

Comment: The exception is probably being thrown from a different thread, outside the scope of your try/catch.

Comment: Sigh... the error is *clearly* being thrown in `LogTxt` if you look at the stack trace but you haven't included that method in your post. Please post the code for it.

Comment: Clearly, your application doesn't have write access to create the log file mentionned in your appSettings.

Comment: So.... have you verified that you have permissions to `logDirectory`? Is it read-only?

Comment: I've checked all the permissions of folders, and all are correct. I need some permission to declare in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
at AndonGestamp_FormMonitoramento.Utils.Log.LogTxt(System.String)
```

shows that the exception stems from LogTxt.

Your conclusion that it is a permission problem is correct.
If you cannot find the problem through visual inspection of your code; trace to *as close as you can* to the row that fails and start [ProcessMonitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645) to find where/what your code tries to reach.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the application running under a account and this account does not have write access to the directory.